# Check setImageWithURL image is loaded or place holder image is set

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview

`[imageView setImageWithURL: url placeholderImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"DefaultBanner"]];`

Using this code I am loading an image from a URL. The form does not submit until the image is not loaded from URL.

Can anyone assist me to fix this code?

Comment: Can you please post more of your code, so that we can see the context where this code is running. See [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a thread concurrency problem, if you handle everything in the main thread it will freeze until the asset is totally downloaded. I will recommend send it to a serial queue in a background thread and after the download is done, send it to the main thread.

an example of that:

```
-(void) GCDSerialQueuesDownload
{
    NSString * anURL = @"myURL.com";
    dispatch_queue_t serialQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.dispatch.feed.serial.queue",DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
    dispatch_queue_t mainQueue = dispatch_get_main_queue();

    void (^addFeedBlock)(NSString*) = ^(NSString* url) {
        //your download here
        dispatch_async(mainQueue,^{
            //after finish you download
        });
    };

    dispatch_async(serialQueue, ^{
        addFeedBlock(anURL);
    });

}
```

[A good source](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)